# Elliptic cone dimensions such that mutually perpendicular axes can be drawn on its surface

Tags: geometry, 3d, quadrics

Given the elliptic cone $r^T Q r = 0 $ , where $ r= [x, y, z]^T $ and

$$ Q = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{a^2} && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && \dfrac{1}{b^2} && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && -1 \end{bmatrix} $$

And suppose $ U, V, W$ are three mutually perpendicular vectors.  Find the condition on $a$ and $b$, such that **if $U$ is contained in the surface of the cone, then so are $V$ and $W$**.

**My attempt:**

From the given structure of matrix $Q$, we can see that a vector contained in the surface of this elliptic cone has the form:

$ U = k [ a \cos s , b \sin s , 1 ]^T $

Since we're talking about angles and not lengths, we can take $ k = 1$.

The plane perpendicular to $U$ (which is to contain $V$ and $W$) has the equation

$ a \cos s \ x + b \sin s \ y + z = 0 $

Intersecting this plane with the cone, gives

$ \dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} = (a \cos s \ x + b \sin s \ y )^2 $

which is a homogeneous equation of $x$ and $y$.  Let $m = \dfrac{y}{x} $ , then dividing the above equation by $x^2$ gives

$ \dfrac{1}{a^2} + \dfrac{m^2}{b^2} = ( a \cos s + b \sin s m )^2 $

which is a quadratic equation in $m$.   If $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the solution, then vectors $V$ and $W$ are given by

$ V = (x_1, y_1, z_1) = x_1 ( 1 , m_1 , a \cos s + b \sin s \ m_1 ) $

$ W = (x_2, y_2, z_2) = x_2 (1, m_2, a \cos s + b \sin s \ m_2 ) $

Imposing orthogonality between $V$ and $W$ and using Vieta's formulas applied to the above quadratic equation, will lead to the required condition on the parameters $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the question statement, we now have the following quadratic equation in $m = \dfrac{y}{x} $

$ m^2 ( b^2 \sin^2 s - \dfrac{1}{b^2} ) + m (a b \sin(2 s) ) + (a^2 \cos^2 s - \dfrac{1}{a^2} ) = 0 $

The two solutions $m_1 , m_2$ satisfy Vieta's formulas

$ m_1 m_2 = (a^2 C^2 - \dfrac{1}{a^2}) / (b^2 S^2 - \dfrac{1}{b^2} ) $

$ m_1 + m_2 = - a b \sin(2 s) / (b^2 S^2 - \dfrac{1}{b^2} ) $

Orthogonality of the two vectors implies

$1 + m_1 m_2 + (a C + b S m_1) (a C + b S m_2) = 0$

Substituting the above expressions for $m_1m_2$ and $m_1 + m_2$ into this gives us, after simplification

$\boxed{  \dfrac{1}{a^2} + \dfrac{1}{b^2} =1 }$

The following [Sagecell.Sagemath.Org page](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1kt9uqkAQxu9NfIdJzgW7Oiq79KJJw5MYa9aVWFJkObtbqj79mVmQnrRWAwzD982fH_TGi8wovOAVb2jwgBEDglV0aDoKBNN0bwbhUEWDnwi9ap0_01XzNZPzmVFQQr5-ms8qS5FRi8urhiUItTJKLq50s4IbnUla6vwFIqm6WshNMZ_1bO4rG50XW-uCiHIT_vooyIoQ6nZKpGoIakct2cftyZue9Wqb71JTitQUaY6S3HKbsbxRdK_ZOlQfKlOuoJxi9R8CkNRBUiHSsjLFaVVehKHwstG0WiRUXIIhcZa9sFKwGcazKk1k9auWPE9gTaqwTFzvGNRmxEsdev0NTPgOJjwAM7yVOxZ6SRMXPXHRE5ehh6YxBx9lijTH2noXwr7z7vhhCa-W90cF8zn5sj53TW3ruO8aF4ujqCyCuODKoJEorhQsxmlHvhJ_ZEh4w_wrT4n5DH75cZ995-o2hvI5J96ucb7Mmvr0Fk--qtoMXWdoomuZrzWa0BG7vTexduVWIf138mUYHpZlZ7w5V9HX9r7A56Knj17QF07FdS6nDr46ZnL50KDxP_0oPzQfVSZh6gQPnQU7c_zqQ2yzo_HvwypysP8DqHb9mA==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) contains an example for such a cone described by

$r^T Q r = 0 $ with $Q = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1-a_1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && -1 \end{bmatrix} $ with $ 0 \lt a_1 \lt 1 $

and a possible set of three mutually perpendicular vectors embedded in it.  You can freely rotate the view, by holding down the left mouse button and dragging, inside the plot window.